# Hide menu items (li) at different screen resolutions

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm breaking my head over this to no avail,

This is the html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<ul id="megamenuiqit" class="clearfix">
<li class="megamenu_home">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu2 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu3 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu5 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu6 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu7 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu8 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu9 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu10 ">
<li class="mainmegamenu id_menu11 ">
<span class="main_menu_link id_menu_link11 linkHover" style="">Mais</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide the item id_menu11 when screen_res is under 1024, I'm using this css:

```
@media (max-width:1024px){

#megamenuiqt ul li.mainmegamenu.idmenu11{display:none;}
```

I know the selector query is not right, but I've tried everything I could think off and its not working it still displays.... what am I doing wrong? Can someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is two-fold.

1. You have a spelling inconsistency between `megamenuiqit` and `megamenuiqt`.
2. `#megamenuiqit` is the `ul` element itself, it does not have a child `ul` element.

Simply remove `ul` from the selector and correct the spelling.

```
#megamenuiqit li.mainmegamenu.id_menu11 {display:none;}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for trying to help, I've tried your suggestion and it still does not work, shouldnt it hide that li element when the window width is smaller then 1024?

Comment: @RicardoMustra Make sure you are using the updated code, I had missed the spelling inconsistency. You media query should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an underscore on `.id_menu11`. You are also not closing divs or the @media block.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul id="megamenuiqit" class="clearfix">
      <li class="megamenu_home">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu2 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu3 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu5 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu6 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu7 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu8 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu9 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu10 ">
      <li class="mainmegamenu id_menu11 ">
      <span class="main_menu_link id_menu_link11 linkHover" style="">Mais</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media ( max-width:1024px ) {
  #megamenuiqit li.mainmegamenu.id_menu11 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```